# WebIntent gives me 'ActivityNotFoundException'

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins, webintents

I am a newbie to cordova apps. In my app, I am trying to add webintent from `https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent`. 
When I run my code, I get the following in my logcat -

```
W/System.err(6378): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
W/System.err(6378):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
W/System.err(6378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
W/System.err(6378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
W/System.err(6378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
W/System.err(6378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
at com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent.startActivity(WebIntent.java:204)
at com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent.execute(WebIntent.java:65)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:229)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:655)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using the following code to call webintent -

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
                      action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
                      url: 'http://www.google.com',
                      type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
               },
               function() {},
               function() {
                 alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.');
                 console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent.");
               }
            );
```

I have also added the required lines to config.xml as written in the github link. Please help me to solve my error.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to protocol
use https instead of http